# Why is my code printing more than once?

Tags: python

```
number = raw_input("Please enter the fixture number: ")
    myfile = open('file.txt')
    for line in myfile:
        item = line.split(',')
        if item[0] == number:
            title = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20} {5:20}'.format('Fixture number', 'date', 'nickname1', 'nickname2', 'Fixture Played', 'Winning Nickname')
            print(title)
            result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20} {5:20}'.format(item[0],item[1],item[3],item[4],item[5],item[6])
            print(result)
        elif item[0] != number:
            print("not exist")
```

Hi there I am new with python, so recently I encountered a problem my

```
elif item[0] != number:
```

is printing "not exist" for the amount of lines in my file
how do I get it to print only once if it is wrong?

Comment: If you don't mind your for loop exiting after `item[0] != number`, you can just add `break` after the print function

Comment: @JGut, that would exit the loop after the first non-match. It's probably the intent to scan the entire file for a match

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set a flag when `item[0] == number` is `True`. Check this flag after the loop terminates, and print `"not exist"` if the flag is set:

```
myfile = open('file.txt')
found = False
for line in myfile:
    item = line.split(',')
    if item[0] == number:
        found = True
        title = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20} {5:20}'.format('Fixture number', 'date', 'nickname1', 'nickname2', 'Fixture Played', 'Winning Nickname')
        print(title)
        result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20} {5:20}'.format(item[0],item[1],item[3],item[4],item[5],item[6])
        print(result)

if not found:
    print("not exist")
```

An alternative is to use the `else` option with the for loop, however, that requires that you want to print only the first time that `item[0] == number` is `True` (because you would need to `break` out of the loop to prevent the `else` clause triggering).

Answer (score 0):

You can attach an `else` clause to the [for loop](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-for-statement) like this:

```
number = raw_input("Please enter the fixture number: ")
myfile = open('file.txt')
for line in myfile:
    item = line.split(',')
    if item[0] == number:
        title = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20} {5:20}'.format('Fixture number', 'date', 'nickname1', 'nickname2', 'Fixture Played', 'Winning Nickname')
        print(title)
        result = '{0:20} {1:20} {2:20} {3:20} {4:20} {5:20}'.format(item[0],item[1],item[3],item[4],item[5],item[6])
        print(result)
        break
else:
    print("not exist")
```

Notice the `break`. The for loop will exit after the first match (via the `break`). If the for loop terminates normally (ie. no match), the else block will run